# How to return the parameter value in Racket?

Tags: scheme, return, racket, reverse

I have to create a Racket scheme that would return the reverse of a list. I cannot use the built in reverse method or anything like it.
So far I have done everything to reverse, but the problem is that my method is not returning the value, it is keeping it instead.
This is what I have done:

```
#lang racket

(define (rev x) 
  (define n '())
  (define i (- (length x) 1))
  (let loop ()
    (when (> i -1)
      (set! n (append n (list (list-ref x i))))
      (set! i (sub1 i))
      (loop)))
  (set! x n)
  "in method display"
  (displayln x))

"display"
(define letters'("a" "b" "c"))
(rev letters)
"in main program display"
(displayln letters)
```

when I print inside the method, I get (c b a) but when I print from the main program I get (a b c) which means that my method is not returning the value. What should I do?

this method is returning void, how can I make it return a value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very last expression evaluated in a procedure is what gets "returned" so in `rev` it's `(displayln x)` and it returns a void. If you changed the last element to be n like this:

```
(define (rev x) 
  (define n '())
  (define i (- (length x) 1))
  (let loop ()
    (when (> i -1)
      (set! n (append n (list (list-ref x i))))
      (set! i (sub1 i))
      (loop)))
  (set! x n)
  "in method display"
  (displayln x)
  n) ; evaluates n last!
```

It would return the result as well. This code is very imperative for Scheme. Without changing how you solved this you could move `n` and `i` to the named `let`:

```
(define (rev x) 
  (let loop ((n '())
             (i (- (length x) 1)))
    (if (> i -1)                             ; if i is positive
      (loop (append n (list (list-ref x i))) ; then call loop with new n and
            (sub1 i))                        ; new i
      n)))                                   ; else return n
```

A more idiomatic solution would be to `cons` the elements from the start to end into an accumulator. The first element will automatically become the last:

```
(define (rev lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst)                 ; we start with the whole list
             (acc '()))                ; out initial acc is the empty list
    (if (<??> lst)                     ; if lst is empty
        <??>                           ; then return accumulator 
        (loop (<??> lst)               ; else we recurse with the cdr of the list
              (cons <??> acc)))))      ; while adding the car to the beginning of acc
```

Comment: I have done this using recursion, but your way uses one parameter which is better. thanks for telling me about the return.

`(define z '())` <br/>
`(define (rev q i) ` <br/>
`(set! z (list(list-ref q i)))` <br/>
`(set! i (sub1 i))` <br/>
`(if (> i 0) (append z (rev q i))(append z (list(list-ref q i)))))`